# How to direct output of cron job to a specific email address?

Tags: linux, email, debian, ssmtp

So, I almost have this working but I need a little help. I have a perl script that generates log messages. The script is triggered by cron every hour. The emails are getting generated and are sent via `ssmtp`.

The problem I'm having is that the emails are getting sent to `user@hostname` ( `user` is the owner of the script that is run). This results in a bounced email to the email address associated with root.

Here is the cron entry for the script:

`00 * * * * /home/user/perl/update.pl`

Here is my `/etc/aliases` file:

`# /etc/aliases
mailer-daemon: postmaster
postmaster: root
nobody: root
hostmaster: root
usenet: root
news: root
webmaster: root
www: root
ftp: root
abuse: root
noc: root
security: root
root: user`

I'm running Debian Jessie.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to add the line in /etc/aliases:

```
user: yourmail@yourdomain.com
```

And add the following line in /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf:

```
user=yourmail@yourdomain.com
```

Comment: When I do that, I get the following message: "newaliases: Aliases are not used in sSMTP"

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were using postfix (I read too fast). I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but still having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I did `crontab -e` and placed the following at the top of the file:

`MAILTO=me@mydomain.com`